# How to analyse: only if ‘but for'?

Tags: meaning, legalese

Source: p 20, *Criminal Law: The Basics*, 1 ed (2009), by Herring

> As we have just noticed, most crimes involve proof that the
>   defendant caused a harm. ... If the defendant stabs the victim, and the
>   victim falls down dead, there can be little doubt that the defendant
>   caused the death of the victim. However, there can be cases where
>   the causation question is far from straightforward.
>     A good starting point is the principle that the defendant can be
>   said to have caused a result **only if ‘[but for](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/but-for?q=but+for)’** his or her act the harm
>   would not have happened. This is sometimes known as factual
>   causation. So in one case (*White*) a defendant poisoned his elderly
>   mother’s tea. Before she took a sip she suffered a heart attack. The
>   medical evidence showed that her heart attack was unrelated to the
>   poisoning. In other words, she would have died in exactly the same
>   way and at exactly the same time had she not drunk the poison.
>   The result was that he could not be said to have caused her death.
>   However, he could be charged with attempted murder.

Based on the link, I know that ***but* for = *1. except* for**. Still, even after substituting with this, I don't understand how to parse the bolded: **only if '*except* for'**? Please explain and show all steps and thought processes; I’d like to try to resolve this myself in the future?

Comment: *Only if 'but for'* is not a constituent. The phrase *but for his or her act* modifies the clause *the harm would not have happened*, and that clause is the complement of *only if*. You may flip the clause and the modifier without no change in sense: "...only if the harm would not have happened 'but for' his or her act".

Comment: It's an unusual sequence of those particular words that's only really likely to arise in a stilted "legalese" context. Think of it as *...the defendant is responsible **only if the following statement is true:*** followed by a separate sentence. Then rearrange the sequence to *"[It] wouldn't have happened **but for** [what he did]"*. That may make it easier for you to see the way it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's why good style encourages using positive instead of double negative clauses... and the quotes only confuse the matters more by separating the expression from the sentence it applies to.

> ‘but for’ his or her act the harm would not have happened.

this could be rephrased, by removing the double negative, as

> only due to his or her act the harm would have happened.

And in this context the becomes quite clear.

the defendant can be said to have caused a result only if [only due to his or her act the harm would have happened.]

I guess the writer tried to avoid the repetition of 'only', and as result made this quite hard to comprehend.

> *"**A** is only true if only X is true."* so, there are factors **X,Y,Z** and for the conclusion **A** to be true, **X** must be true, while **Y** and **Z** must be false. In all other cases **A** is false.

got transliterated as

> *"**A** is only true if [if not for **X** being true, all factors would be false]"

...and phrased it with awkward punctuation and rare and unintuitive use of *but*.

A stylistically better and clearer phrasing would switch the phrases around a bit and add both variants of outcome:

> the defendant can be said to have caused a result only if the harm would have happened due to his or her act, and not for any other reasons.

Comment: criminal law, **the basics**! I don't want to read their books on advanced stuff. Damn!

Comment: @linuxUser123: That's the problem with legalese. It's formally grammatically correct, but stylistically abhorrent.